# Laravel Eloquent how to select relation field as certain fields of main object

Tags: php, laravel, select, laravel-4, eloquent

```
$select = Model::with(['relation' => function($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'somefield');
}])->get();
```

When using this code I get my `Model` object with `relation` field which contains `somefield`.

```
{
    ... some Model fields
    ...
    relation => {
        id => someid
        somefield => somevalue
    }
}
```

But what if I need `somefield` to be the field of `Model` instead?

```
{
    ... some Model fields
    ...

    somefield => somevalue
}
```

Edit: In other words I want to get the same result as following query, using Eloquent

```
\DB::table('table1')
    ->select('table1.field1', 'table2.field2 as otherfield', 
    ->leftJoin('table2', 'table2.id', '=', 'table1.parent_id')->get();
```

Comment: Can you do model.somefield?

Comment: @Anoxy I want to be able to call Model->somefield, not Model->relation->somefield

Comment: I would just use the laravel pluck function then example: $shopAddresses = Shop::where('name', 'Starbucks')->pluck('address');

Answer (score 0):

Use the Laravel plcuk method like so:

```
$shopAddresses = Shop::where('name', 'Starbucks')->pluck('address');
```

Comment: You should be able to do     ->pluck('address, 'joinfield.address)